# Nested Select in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I hope that I am not repeating previously answered questions but I don't even know where to start here.

I have 3 tables. Sales, Production and Collections.
The production and collections tables have a many-to-one relationship with the Sales table on the salesID column.

I want to create a query from a date range on the Sales Table which also pulls all production and collections data with matching salesID. Do I use a nested select statement here??

Thanks for the help.
Nic

Comment: Can you post what have you tried?

Comment: Try some stuff. If it doesn't do what you expected, please ask about *that*.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a pretty typical SQL statement, but you want to aggregate the columns from production and collections.

```
select s.salesID, 
       s.customerID, 
       s.productID, 
       s.salesDate, 
       MIN(p.productionDate), 
       SUM(p.productionQty), 
       SUM(c.collectionQty), 
       MIN(c.collectionDate), 
       r.productName 
from sales s 
inner join production p on s.salesID = p.salesID 
inner join collections c on s.salesID = c.salesID 
inner join products r on s.productID = r.productID 
group by s.salesID, s.customerID, s.productID, s.salesDate, r.productName
```

Comment: YMMV - That's just the direction I needed. Much appreciated. So now I have the following:

`select s.salesID, s.customerID, s.productID, salesDate, p.productionDate, productionQty, c.collectionQty, c.collectionDate, r.productName
from sales s
inner join production p on s.salesID = p.salesID
inner join collections c on s.salesID = c.salesID
inner join products r on s.productID = r.productID
order by s.salesID`

In this scenario, I will have one sales record but multiple production and collection records. How would I sum up the production and collections to return single rows for each sale?

Comment: @YMMV - is it possible to take this offline for a while as I can't explain my needs in this short space and I really need help.
Thanks

Comment: Based on your comments I have modified my answer.  And my name is Bill Gregg.  YMMV is short hand for "Your Mileage May Vary" indicating that since I didn't know your schema, I just gave an example of what I thought you wanted.  Good luck!

Comment: YMMV :-) Thanks Bill Gregg! You're a legend.

Comment: Hi Bill I am back. I have really struggled to get a meaningful result from playing with this query. Is there anyway I could send you the schema along with the result I need? It's a lot to ask but I am totally stuck here!

Comment: Why don't you edit this question to include the schema.  You should have included it anyway.  Also, have you tried creating a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)?  That way people can help you without having to recreate your schema and data.  Help us help you.  Don't ask us to just do your work for you.